# sidebar widgets are minimized too when pressing "show desktop"

Tags: windows-7, sidebar

Windows 7 x64:

I thought my sidebar widgets shouldn't be minimized (only normal windows) when I push the field *show desktop* on the right  bottom corner. But now they are minimzed every time I want to go to my desktop. Very annoying. **Is that normal?**

If so: Is there a way to change this so that they aren't touched if 'show '

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like it a known behavior. Check out the following thread, hopefully they fix it soon.

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/w7itproui/thread/a9829215-5d8f-4da0-815a-ed61cc9fab3f

Seems like there isn't anything you can do so far.

Comment: so its a IE9 Beta bug, good to know.
thanks for the link!

Comment: can be solved by uninstalling IE9 beta, if you want so. I tested it.